# How can I recover my external drive's partition table?

Tags: terminal, macos, partition, guid

I have an old WD MyBook Ext Drive and I couldn't access the greyed out sub-partition in DiskUtility. I was trying to fix it with various Terminal commands relating to GPT and somehow I managed to mess up the partition table.

This is what I get from $ diskutil list:

```
    /dev/disk1 (external, physical):
    #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       
IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
```

And this is what I get from: $ sudo gpt show disk1

```
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34  976773101                               
976773135         32         Sec GPT table
976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

I know the data is on there but I think the table needs to be rebuilt, but have zero clue to get there.....

Can anyone give me pointers as to how to do this? It's a 500gb WD drive.

EDIT:

Another user pointed out that I posted about this disk a year ago but never got a resolution. Here is the additional info from that disk BEFORE I managed to mess with it and delete the partition table:

```
/dev/disk2
 #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
 0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk2
 1:        Apple_partition_map                         32.3 KB    disk2s1
 2:                  Apple_HFS General DATA            500.0 GB   disk2s3
```

Also from that that other thread prior ot me messing with it:

```
  $ diskutil info /dev/disk1
  Device Identifier:        disk1
  Device Node:              /dev/disk1
  Whole:                    Yes
  Part of Whole:            disk1
  Device / Media Name:      WD

  Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
  Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
  File System:              None

  Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
  OS Can Be Installed:      No
  Media Type:               Generic
  Protocol:                 FireWire
  SMART Status:             Not Supported

  Disk Size:                500.1 GB (500107862016 Bytes) (exactly 976773168 
  512-Byte-Units)
  Device Block Size:        512 Bytes
```

Here is the result TODAY of the command from @klanomath

```
   $ sudo dd if=/dev/disk1 skip=409640 bs=512 count=3 | hexdump

   3+0 records in
   3+0 records out
   1536 bytes transferred in 0.510661 secs (3008 bytes/sec)
   0000000 00 63 00 74 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 06
   0000010 00 24 ba 6b 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 24 ba 69 00 0b
   0000020 00 52 00 65 00 6d 00 6f 00 76 00 65 00 2e 00 74
   0000030 00 69 00 66 00 66 00 06 00 24 ba 6c 00 00 00 04
   0000040 00 00 00 24 b5 71 00 11 00 49 00 6e 00 66 00 6f
   0000050 00 50 00 6c 00 69 00 73 00 74 00 2e 00 73 00 74
   0000060 00 72 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00 73 00 06 00 24 ba 6d
   0000070 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 24 b5 71 00 0e 00 49 00 6e
   0000080 00 66 00 6f 00 57 00 69 00 6e 00 64 00 6f 00 77
   0000090 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 26 00 24 ba 6d 00 10
   00000a0 00 6b 00 65 00 79 00 65 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 6a
   00000b0 00 65 00 63 00 74 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62
   00000c0 00 02 00 0e 00 00 00 00 00 24 ba 6e c5 af fc b0
   00000d0 c5 af fc b0 ce fa 08 d7 ce fa 08 d7 00 00 00 00
   00000e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 81 b4 00 00 00 01
   00000f0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   0000110 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 f2
   0000120 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 02 84 6f 36 00 00 00 02
   0000130 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   00001b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 24 ba 6e 00 00
   00001c0 00 04 00 00 00 24 ba 6d 00 10 00 6b 00 65 00 79
   00001d0 00 65 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 6a 00 65 00 63 00 74
   00001e0 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 06 00 24 ba 6f
   00001f0 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 24 b5 71 00 23 00 69 00 50
   0000200 00 61 00 64 00 20 00 61 00 6e 00 64 00 20 00 69
   0000210 00 50 00 68 00 6f 00 6e 00 65 00 34 00 2e 00 63
   0000220 00 6f 00 6d 00 70 00 72 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 6f
   0000230 00 72 00 54 00 65 00 6d 00 70 00 6c 00 61 00 74
   0000240 00 65 00 06 00 24 ba 70 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 24
   0000250 b5 71 00 0b 00 4a 00 6f 00 62 00 54 00 69 00 6c
   0000260 00 65 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 26 00 24 ba 70
   0000270 00 10 00 6b 00 65 00 79 00 65 00 64 00 6f 00 62
   0000280 00 6a 00 65 00 63 00 74 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69
   0000290 00 62 00 02 00 0e 00 00 00 00 00 24 ba 71 c6 0b
   00002a0 20 90 c6 0b 20 90 ce fa 08 d7 ce fa 08 d7 00 00
   00002b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 81 b4 00 00
   00002c0 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   00002d0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   00002f0 50 e2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 02 84 6f 3a 00 00
   0000300 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   0000310 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   0000380 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 24 ba 71
   0000390 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 24 ba 70 00 10 00 6b 00 65
   00003a0 00 79 00 65 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 6a 00 65 00 63
   00003b0 00 74 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 06 00 24
   00003c0 ba 72 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 24 b5 71 00 07 00 4c
   00003d0 00 61 00 79 00 6f 00 75 00 74 00 73 00 40 00 24
   00003e0 ba 72 00 1d 00 43 00 6f 00 6d 00 70 00 72 00 65
   00003f0 00 73 00 73 00 6f 00 72 00 2e 00 73 00 61 00 76
   0000400 00 65 00 64 00 2e 00 6d 00 6f 00 64 00 75 00 6c
   0000410 00 65 00 4c 00 61 00 79 00 6f 00 75 00 74 00 02
   0000420 00 0e 00 00 00 00 00 24 ba 73 c2 25 0f 72 c2 25
   0000430 0f 72 ce fa 08 d7 ce fa 08 d7 00 00 00 00 00 00
   0000440 00 00 00 00 00 50 00 00 81 b4 00 00 00 01 00 00
   0000450 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   0000470 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 c7 00 00
   0000480 00 00 00 00 00 02 02 84 6f 40 00 00 00 02 00 00
   0000490 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   *
   0000510 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 06 00 24 ba 73 00 00 00 04
   0000520 00 00 00 24 ba 72 00 1d 00 43 00 6f 00 6d 00 70
   0000530 00 72 00 65 00 73 00 73 00 6f 00 72 00 2e 00 73
   0000540 00 61 00 76 00 65 00 64 00 2e 00 6d 00 6f 00 64
   0000550 00 75 00 6c 00 65 00 4c 00 61 00 79 00 6f 00 75
   0000560 00 74 00 06 00 24 ba 74 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 24
   0000570 b5 71 00 13 00 4c 00 6f 00 63 00 61 00 6c 00 69
   0000580 00 7a 00 61 00 62 00 6c 00 65 00 2e 00 73 00 74
   0000590 00 72 00 69 00 6e 00 67 00 73 00 06 00 24 ba 75
   00005a0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 24 b5 71 00 0c 00 4d 00 61
   00005b0 00 69 00 6e 00 4d 00 65 00 6e 00 75 00 2e 00 6e
   00005c0 00 69 00 62 00 26 00 24 ba 75 00 10 00 6b 00 65
   00005d0 00 79 00 65 00 64 00 6f 00 62 00 6a 00 65 00 63
   00005e0 00 74 00 73 00 2e 00 6e 00 69 00 62 00 02 00 0e
   00005f0 00 00 00 00 00 24 ba 76 c6 0a f7 a1 c6 0a f7 a1
   0000600
```

Any help SUPER appreciated.

Comment: Another disk of yours: [WD external drive won't mount in OSX - partition map rebuild?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/271467/wd-external-drive-wont-mount-in-osx-partition-map-rebuild) or the same one?

Comment: @klanomath - Huh, must be mine. I completely forgot about that. Thank you it's actually really helpful becuase it has the state (partition table) of the drive before I messed with it!

Comment: I've added all the data I can think of, please let me know what else I should add @klanomath

Comment: OK, GPT is obviously the wrong partition scheme ;-) (the dd output suggests the same because it's nothing I'd expect for this kind of scheme).

Comment: OK, thanks, so any pointers on how to fix? @klanomath

Comment: Revert to Apple_partition_map ;-). I have to consult the manual...

Comment: Any ideas @klanomath?