# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 Windows 8 install on SSD

Tags: macos, bootcamp, efi

I am trying to install Windows 8, efi, on my SSD. I am getting the error code:

```
 0xC0000005 "Windows installation encountered an unexpected error. Verify that the installation sources are accesible, and restart the installation everytime"
```

I have tried all the solutions on [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5515428?start=15&tstart=0):  which is basically try formatting exfat, then installing; the setup stops at 89% in step2 and gives the above error. I also tried the procedure [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/2fy3be/by_popular_demand_my_better_than_bootcamp_guide/):  I get the error code above in step1 of the install.

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
  #                  TYPE NAME                  SIZE    IDENTIFIER 
  0 GUID_partition_scheme                     *250.1 GB disk0      
  1                   EFI NO NAME              209.7 MB disk0sl    
  2    Microsoft Reserved                      134.2 MB disk0s2    
  3  Microsoft Basic Data Windows              249.1 GB disk0s3    
/dev/diskl                                                        
  #                  TYPE NAME                  SIZE    IDENTIFIER 
  0 GUID_partition_scheme                     *500.1 GB diskl      
  1                   EFI EFI                  209.7 MB disklsl    
  2     Apple_CoreStorage                      77.7 GB  diskls2    
  3            Apple_Boot Recovery HD          650.0 MB diskls3    
  4 DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC       314.6 MB diskls4    
  5                   EFI NO NAME              104.9 MB diskls5    
  6 DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC       314.6 MB diskls6    
  7                   EFI NO NAME              104.9 MB diskls7    
/dev/disk2                                                        
  #:                 TYPE NAME                  SIZE    IDENTIFIER 
  0:            Apple_HFS Untitled        *77.3 GB      disk2      
                          Logical Volume  on diskls2               
                          46DF977A-1EE0-4AC9-B400-EF63F6190E87
                          Unencrypted
```

`diskutil cs list`:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group C0048D6F-43CA-4B3C-8D5F-D17CC77DCA92
    =========================================================
    Name:           Untitled
    Status:         Online
    Size:           77695913984 B (77.7 GB)
    Free Space:     0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 393E8C61-3969-4BBD-8224-35BA98978AA8
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:      0
    |   Disk:       diskls2
    |   Status:     Online
    |   Size:       77695913984 B (77.7 GB)
    |  
    +-> Logical Volume Family 83CBFA4C-FCF0-49CB-812A-7945C8D102B6
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:      Unlocked
        Encryption Type:        None
        Conversion Status:      NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:   -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:  No
        Fully Secure:           No
        Passphrase Required:    No
        |  
        +-> Logical Volume 46DF977A-1EE0-4AC9-B400-EF63F6190E87
            -------------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                   disk2
            Status:                 Online
            Size (Total):           77343592448 B (77.3 GB)
            Conversion Progress:    -none-
            Revertible:             Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:                Untitled
            Volume Name:            Untitled
            Content Hint:           Apple_HFS
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: welcome, as you could guess your problem is not very common around here, so it might take a while till someone can answer it.

Comment: @ArnavShah Please add your current Mac OS X and the output of `diskutil list` and if applicable `diskutil cs list` entered in Terminal.app to your question.

Comment: @ArnavShah ...and examining the diskutil listings probably Yosemite as current Mac OS X ;-)

Comment: @ArnavShah Did you already try [this](http://blog.thedeltaflyer.com/2013/01/dual-booting-windows-8-and-mountain-lion-natively-using-efi/) solution?

Comment: I did try something similar, the only difference is I used cmd after clicking the efi boot icon.

Comment: Which disk is the SSD. It appears you are trying to install on disk1. Are disk0 and disk1 internal or external drives?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Everything is internal, I replaced my optical drive with the ssd. disk0 is the ssd that I want windows8 installed on, BUT when I use diskpart list disk on the windows installer, its actually disk 1 that is my ssd. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have a solution. I do have more questions.

You seem to be trying very hard to use the GUID partition table to boot Windows. Most Windows users just rely on the MBR in the hybrid partition table. Why do you feel you need to make the extra effort? What do you hope to gain?

Is your Mac a MacBookPro9,2 (13-inch), MacBook9,1 (15-inch) or MacBookPro10,1 (Retina)?

Do know if your firmware is up to date? See [EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518).

I assume you are booting from a flash drive to install windows. How did you create the flash drive? Did you need to modify the Boot Camp Assistant?

Could you post the output from the following commands? The commands do not alter anything.

```
sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
sudo fdisk /dev/disk1
```

Which Windows: 8 or 8.1? 64 bit or 32 bit? Full or upgrade version?

OS X is Yosemite?

You are using Core Storage. Would you be opposed to not using it. I don't know what good Core Storage is unless you have a Fusion Drive.

Have you configured the OS X Disk Utility application to display hidden partitions? If not, see [View & Mount Hidden Partitions in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/23/view-mount-hidden-partitions-in-mac-os-x/). I do not want you to mount the hidden partitions, just make them visible.

You say you want to install on disk 0. You seem to have collected some partitions on disk 1. Do you need help removing them?

Finally, you may discover you can not install Windows because you removed the DVD drive.

Comment: Ended up swapping the harddrives; have to wait for EFI boot to end or hold option to boot in Windows =/

Comment: @Arnav: So I assume you now have windows installed using EFI boot? If so, is having to hold the option key a problem? There are utilities to help with that. A free one is rEFInd and a $10 one is Boot Runner (14 free trial). Also, I assume you know how to boot between OS X and Windows without having to hold a key down.

Comment: I installed Windows through the Windows USB icon (not the EFI boot one), so I'm not sure if there was even an EFI partition installed. I tried doing the first step on this [page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows),mountvol S: /S, but I got an error: "The parameter above is incorrect."

Comment: @Arnav: An easy way to determine whether you installed Windows in EFI is to use [this test](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169680/does-windows-running-on-latest-apple-computers-see-boot-disk-partitioned-as-mb). If you get a * in the Gpt column, then you succeeded. My guess is you did not, which would make Boot Runner a better choice as a startup manager. Anyway, I do not use either and rely on Boot Camp in Windows and System Preferences in OS X to switch operating systems.