# HFS+ Partition of Mac OSX is not recognized in Windows 10 Bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, hfs+

I installed triple systems (Mac, Windows, Linux) on my Macbook Pro retina mid 2014 with rEFInd boot loader. Hfs+ partition used to be visible in Windows 8.1 Bootcamp.

But after updating to Windows 10, it doesn't show up again. I don't enable FileVault. HFS+ drivers installed on Windows 10 with the latest Bootcamp support drivers.

Please help! Thank you so much.

Below is the output from the following Terminal application commands.

```
diskutil list
diskutil cs list
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0
sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if Windows 10 is booting in BIOS or EFI mode? Instructions for testing are given [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169680/does-windows-running-on-latest-apple-computers-see-boot-disk-partitioned-as-mb). Also, could you post, to your answer, the output from the following Terminal application commands: `diskutil  list`, `diskutil  cs  list`, `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0`. These commands will not change your computer. Some may ask for your login password. This is normal.

Comment: Windows 10 boots in BIOS.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kKe6HQ3.png Here are the results by running those commands. Thank you so much!

Comment: I need to know if your version of Linux includes the `gdisk` command. Boot to Linux and open a Terminal window. At the prompt, enter the command `gdisk` and report back if the command was found.

Comment: Hello David, here is it: GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1 my Linux system is Ubuntu 16.04 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computer uses two partition tables stored on your internal drive. The first is the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table and the second is the GUID Partition Table (GPT). You used the commands `fdisk` and `gpt` to print out most of the contents of the MBR partition table and GPT, respectively.

For the most part, Windows (booted via BIOS) ignores the GPT and uses the MBR table exclusively to determine the partitions on your internal drive. For Macs, the usual requirement is for the first partition in the MBR table to have an id=`EE`. Also this partition should start at a Logical Block Address (LBA) of 1 and end at the same LBA as the EFI partition in the GPT. (The EFI partition has an GUID=`C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B`.)

Your MBR partition table contains the following problems:

1. Your first partition (id=`EE`) extends past the EFI partition in the
   GPT. In fact, this partition covers the first three partitions in the
   GPT.
2. The last partition (number 4) is empty. This probably where the HFS+
   partition information was stored before you updated to Windows 10.
3. The partitions are not in ascending order. I do not know if this one
   has to be fixed. For now, I will ignore this problem.

One of the easiest commands that can fix these types of problems is `gdisk`. This command can be found in most Linux installs. Below is a example of how to use the command to fix your Mac. In the example, this command was run under OS X. I assume you will be using Linux, therefore you should substitute `/dev/sda` for `/dev/disk0`.

```
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$ gdisk /dev/disk0
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1

Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: hybrid
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with hybrid MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): h

WARNING! Hybrid MBRs are flaky and dangerous! If you decide not to use one,
just hit the Enter key at the below prompt and your MBR partition table will
be untouched.

Type from one to three GPT partition numbers, separated by spaces, to be
added to the hybrid MBR, in sequence: 5 4 2
Place EFI GPT (0xEE) partition first in MBR (good for GRUB)? (Y/N): y

Creating entry for GPT partition #5 (MBR partition #2)
Enter an MBR hex code (default 07): 07
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): y

Creating entry for GPT partition #4 (MBR partition #3)
Enter an MBR hex code (default 83): 83
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): n

Creating entry for GPT partition #2 (MBR partition #4)
Enter an MBR hex code (default AF): af
Set the bootable flag? (Y/N): n

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/disk0.
Warning: Devices opened with shared lock will not have their
partition table automatically reloaded!
Warning: The kernel may continue to use old or deleted partitions.
You should reboot or remove the drive.
The operation has completed successfully.
Steelhead:~ davidanderson$
```

When finished the output from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` should show the following values in the #, id, start and size columns.

```
 #: id      start         size
------------------------------
 1: EE          1       409639   
*2: 07  744597504    214845440
 3: 83  451624920    292970696
 4: AF     409640    449945744
```

If your values are different, update your question and report the differences.

Comment: Oh my god, problem is solved!!! No word can't describe my feeling right now. Thank you so much. I appreciate your kind help a lots. You rock!